# Check for Valid HTML link with SESSIONS

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, validation

One of the first things I like to do when I make a site is to put in links at the bottom of the page to check for valid HTML and CSS:

[HTML5](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer)  •  
[CSS](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/check/referer/)

```
<div>
   <a href="http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer">HTML5</a>
   <a href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/check/referer/">CSS</a>
</div>
```

However, when you have content that you must be logged in to see, these links are useless because all you get is your login page (or error page or whatever).

I would love to be able to cook up some way of grabbing the source using javascript, then sending the string to w3c as post data so it thinks you did the "validate by input" option.. I suppose you could do:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML
```

..but then you don't get the DOCTYPE. Anyone have any ideas? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [HTML validator plugin for FireFox](http://users.skynet.be/mgueury/mozilla/)
- [CSS validator plugin for FireFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2289)

No need for links, and you can use it anywhere while you're developing.

Comment: Thanks for the plugins, they're helpful.. I was actually hoping to have them so that other developers would use them who normally don't! But I suppose these will have to work.